# Configuration space VS Euclidean space

Tags: differential-geometry, space

Why Configuration space is non-Euclidean space? Why it doesn't look like an n-dimensional Euclidean Space in General?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by the term 'configuration space'? Do you mean the manifolds on which you do Lagrangian mechanics (if so, it shouldn't be hard to think of counter examples)?

Comment: Seconding Jacob's comment, without more detail the context, it is impossible to tell what sort of "configuration space" (which really is a term appearing in many different context for different things) you are talking about.

Comment: Be aware that 'Euclidean space' has different meanings in mathematics & physics.